# list files by date added in terminal with function or script or another

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I found this in another post but would like to be able to call a script of function to reduce the amount of typing.

```
ls -a | \
grep -v '^\.$\|^\.\.$' | \
xargs -I {} mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded {} | \
sed 'N;s/\n//' | grep -v '(null)' | \
awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " substr($0,index($0,$7))}' | \
sort -r
```

This is the other post
[Can I list files ordered by date added to a folder from a command-line tool like ls?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86307/can-i-list-files-ordered-by-date-added-to-a-folder-from-a-command-line-tool-like)

Answer (score 1):

Simply create .bash_profile in your home folder or open it, if it already exists:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

and add the following lines:

```
function added {
    ls -a | grep -v '^\.$\|^\.\.$' | xargs -I {} mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded {} | sed 'N;s/\n//' | grep -v '(null)' | awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " substr($0,index($0,$7))}' | sort -r;
}
```

Save the mods with ctrl-o, Enter and quit nano with ctrl-x.

Close the Terminal window, open a new one and then simply enter `added` and you'll get the sorted list of files and folders in your home folder with some glitches though.

The accepted answer in the linked question presents a much faster solution:

```
function added2 {
    mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded -raw * | xargs -0 -I {} echo {} | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sort;
}
```

Comment: to avoid changing directories, `~/` can be used right?

Comment: @ankii The command (or function) is executed in the working directory....

Answer (score 0):

Here's another shell function ( I'm assuming your shell is ksh, zsh, or bash ) - Sets the date, time and UTC offset to zeros if the Date Added metadata is missing

```sh
dateadded () {
mdls -n kMDItemFSName -n kMDItemDateAdded -raw -nullMarker '0 0 0' ./* |
tr '\0' '\n ' | paste -d ' ' - - | sort -rn
}
```

Comment: @ankii, That was a totally unnecessary edit!

Comment: I like appropriate colors @user3439894, you can see rendered output. And it was already on home page